# Algebraic variety and real manifold

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

When an algebraic variety, affine or projective, is a manifold ( on $\mathbb{R}$)? And when the inverse is true?
I think that each algebraic variety is a manifold but for the projective? I would think the same but I would like to have an explanation about the relathionship of these structures

Comment: It is not true that all real affine varieties are manifolds. For example, the variety defined by $((x+1)^2 + y^2 - 1)((x-1)^2 + y^2 - 1) = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a wedge of two circles.

Comment: Perhaps your definition of "variety" requires irreducibility, in which case the above does not work. If so, consider $y^2 = x^3 + x$ instead. This defines an irreducible variety in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is not a manifold: [here's a picture of it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_plane_curve#/media/File:Cubic_with_double_point.svg).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is actually a nontrivial theorem regarding this issue:

**Definition.** 1. A smooth manifold $M$ is **tame** if $M$ is diffeomorphic to the interior of a smooth compact manifold $N$ with (possibly empty) boundary.

2. A smooth manifold $M$ is **algebraic** if it is diffeomorphic to a
   nonsingular real-algebraic subset of ${\mathbb R}^n$ for some $n$.

**Theorem.** A smooth manifold is tame if and only if it is algebraic.

Both directions are nontrivial. See Corollary 4.3 in

*Akbulut, Selman; King, Henry C.*, [**The topology of real algebraic sets with isolated singularities**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2006992), Ann. Math. (2) 113, 425-446 (1981). [ZBL0494.57004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0494.57004).