# The projective plane as a smooth surface in a 4-dimensional space

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, projective-space, birational-geometry

For $(a, b, c)$ pairwise distinct:
$$
\begin{align}
f: & S^2       & \mapsto & \quad \mathbb{R}^4 \\
   & (x, y, z) & \mapsto & \quad (X, Y, Z, W) = (y \cdot z, x \cdot z, x \cdot y, a \cdot x^2 + b \cdot y^2 + c \cdot z^2)
\end{align}
$$
is a smooth double covering map of the real unit sphere $S^2$ to a
surface in the real 4-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^4$, and opposite
points have the same image, such that it can also be interpreted as an
injective embedding of the real projective plane. In particular, the
image of $f()$ is a surface, that is, each point has a non-degenerate
tangential plane.

The image of $f()$ can be defined in the $(X, Y, Z, W)$ coordinates as follows.

If $X \cdot Y \cdot Z \neq 0$:
$$
    (Y \cdot Z)^2 + (X \cdot Z)^2 + (X \cdot Y)^2 = X \cdot Y \cdot Z \\
    a \cdot (Y \cdot Z)^2 + b \cdot (X \cdot Z)^2 + c \cdot (X \cdot Y)^2 = X \cdot Y \cdot Z \cdot W
$$
If $X = Y = 0$ and $Z \neq 0$:
$$
    (a - b)^2 \cdot (1 - 4 \cdot Z^2) = (2 \cdot W - (a + b))^2
$$
If $X = Z = 0$ and $Y \neq 0$:
$$
    (a - c)^2 \cdot (1 - 4 \cdot Z^2) = (2 \cdot W - (a + c))^2
$$
If $Y = Z = 0$ and $X \neq 0$:
$$ 
    (b - c)^2 \cdot (1 - 4 \cdot Z^2) = (2 \cdot W - (b + c))^2
$$
If $X = Y = Z = 0$:
$$ 
    (W - a) \cdot (W - b) \cdot (W - c) = 0
$$

**Question 1**:

Is the image of $f()$ an algebraic set in the $(X, Y, Z, W)$ coordinates ? Can
it be defined by a single ideal, without case analysis ?

If yes, what is the ideal in question, explicitly ?

If no, how to prove it ? Furthermore, the image of f() consists then of five
algebraic pieces fitting together smoothly, without being, as a whole,
algebraic; I find it surprising, what happens where the pieces meet ?

**Question 2**:

If $X \cdot Y \cdot Z \neq 0$, or, equivalently, $x \cdot y \cdot z \neq 0$,
then
$$
    [x : y : z] = [Y \cdot Z : X \cdot Z : X \cdot Y]
$$
Is there a rational formula for each of the other pieces ?

If yes, what are the respective formulæ, explicitly ?

If no, how to prove it ?

Comment: A specialization of this problem to the case $a=1$, $b=-1$, $c=0$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4384976/real-projective-plane-as-real-points-of-affine-variety).

Comment: @KReiser Thanks. That is an answer to question 1 for this particular case, indeed. Thus, there is a single ideal corresponding to the image of $f()$ (at least for the particular case in question, and probably in general, too), but I would not know how to compute it (apparently, I need to learn more about elimination theory; do you have a recommendation?). I will try to play a bit with this explicitly given ideal for understanding it better. The generators of this ideal have been, however, established by computer, and I am wondering if there are more symmetric generators.

Comment: I should have answered to each question, please let me know if you are agree with me :D

Comment: @FedericoFallucca I accepted your answer. I think that your last three equations defining the image of $f()$ are not necessary (indeed, if for instance $X = Y = 0$, the third equation already gives sufficient constraints). It is also possible to prove the bijectivity without real considerations (such that the results hold for any field); that is how I derived the constraints given in the question. As to question 2, I think that polynomial maps exist in the neighborhood of any point except those corresponding to $[0 : 0 : 1]$, $[0 : 1 : 0]$, $[1 : 0 : 0]$. I will post them soon.

Comment: Ok I will see which is your reasoning. However, I think that those equations are necessary. For instance, if $X=Y=0$ and you use only the third equation, then you get a relation between W and Z only for $W\neq c$, otherwise that equation does not give you some information more.  By the way, I will wait what you mean. I will wait something also about question 2 :D.

Comment: @FedericoFallucca You are right, all equations are needed; I overlooked the case where $X = Y = 0$ and $W = c$ and $Z \neq 0$ (and also the other two symmetric cases), which consists of six points. As to question two, another map is, for instance: $[x : y : z] = [(c - a) \cdot Y^2 + (b - a) \cdot Z^2 + (W - b) \cdot Z + (W - c) \cdot Y : (a - b) \cdot Z^2 + (c - b) \cdot X^2 + (W - c) \cdot X + (W - a) \cdot Z : (b - c) \cdot X^2 + (a - c) \cdot Y^2 + (W - a) \cdot Y + (W - b) \cdot X]$.

Comment: Which is the meaning of that map? I don't understand. Are you trying to invert our map?

Comment: @FedericoFallucca Indeed, this is an inverse polynomial map, obtained from the formula $[x : y : z] = [t \cdot Y \cdot Z : t \cdot Z \cdot X : t \cdot Y \cdot X]$ with $t = p \cdot \frac{W - a}{X} + q \cdot \frac{W - b}{Y} + r \cdot \frac{W - c}{Z}$ and $(p, q, r) = (1, 1, 1)$. If $p \cdot q \cdot r \neq 0$ and some of $(X, Y, Z)$ is zero, it is determinate with few exceptions. But it is always indeterminate if $X = Y = Z = 0$; does some map exist for this case (required to produce only inteterminate or correct values) ?

Comment: @FedericoFallucca I posted a partial answer to question 2. I figured out three inverse polynomial maps, but there are exceptional points.

Comment: @KReiser Federico Fallucca has found explicit generators for the ideal in question, whose structure easier to grasp with variable parameters $(a, b, c)$ than with the particular parameters $a = 1$, $b = -1$ and $c = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\bf{Question \ 1:}$

I think you should be more clear:

First of all you say that your map is an embedding of $S^2$ in $\mathbb R^4$. An embedding is injective, and as you said just one second later, your map sends opposites points to the same point.

Moreover, it is not so clear why your map $S^2/\mathbb Z_2\to \mathbb R^4$ should be injective and which is exactly the role of your coefficients $a,b,c$. We have to prove that if two points $(x_0',y_0', z_0')$, $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in S^2$ have the same image, then they are equal or just the opposite to each other.

I have thought to this trick, although I don't know if there is a more easy proof. Remembering that our points are on $S^2$, let us compute

$$(x_0'+y_0'+z_0')^2=1+2x_0'y_0'+2x_0'z_0'+2y_0'z_0'=1+2x_0y_0+2x_0z_0+2y_0z_0=(x_0+y_0+z_0)^2 \implies x_0'+y_0'+z_0'=(-1)^\alpha(x_0+y_0+z_0).$$

However, we can do the same also for others combinations:

$$(x_0'+y_0'-z_0')^2=\dots=(x_0+y_0-z_0)^2 \implies x_0'+y_0'-z_0'=(-1)^\beta(x_0+y_0-z_0),$$

$$(x_0'-y_0'-z_0')^2=\dots=(x_0-y_0-z_0)^2 \implies x_0'+-y_0'-z_0'=(-1)^\gamma(x_0-y_0-z_0).$$

To sumarize, we have got the following linear system

$$ \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1& 1\\ 1 &1& -1\\ 1 &-1&-1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_0' \\ y_0' \\ z_0'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}(-1)^\alpha & 0& 0\\ 0 &(-1)^\beta& 0\\ 0 &0&(-1)^\gamma \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1& 1\\ 1 &1& -1\\ 1 &-1&-1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_0 \\ y_0 \\ z_0\end{pmatrix}.$$

However, the left matrix is invertible and its inverse is

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1& 1\\ 1 &1& -1\\ 1 &-1&-1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0& 1\\ 0 &1& -1\\ 1&-1&0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore, for each fixed $\alpha,\beta, \gamma$ we have got a unique solution

$$ \begin{pmatrix} x_0' \\ y_0' \\ z_0'\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0& 1\\ 0 &1& -1\\ 1&-1&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}(-1)^\alpha & 0& 0\\ 0 &(-1)^\beta& 0\\ 0 &0&(-1)^\gamma \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1& 1\\ 1 &1& -1\\ 1 &-1&-1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_0 \\ y_0 \\ z_0\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0& 1\\ 0 &1& -1\\ 1&-1&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}(-1)^\alpha & (-1)^\alpha& (-1)^\alpha\\ (-1)^\beta &(-1)^\beta& (-1)^{\beta+1}\\ (-1)^\gamma &(-1)^{\gamma+1}&(-1)^{\gamma+1} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_0 \\ y_0 \\ z_0\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}(-1)^\alpha+(-1)^\gamma & (-1)^\alpha+(-1)^{\gamma+1}& (-1)^\alpha+(-1)^{\gamma+1}\\ (-1)^\beta+(-1)^{\gamma+1} &(-1)^\beta+(-1)^\gamma& (-1)^{\beta+1}+(-1)^\gamma\\ (-1)^\alpha+(-1)^{\beta+1} &(-1)^\alpha+(-1)^{\beta+1}&(-1)^\alpha+(-1)^{\beta}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_0 \\ y_0 \\ z_0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Observe that if $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=(0,0,0)$, then the solution is trivial, and is $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. Instead, if $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=(1,1,1)$, then the solution is trivial too, and it is the opposite point $(-x_0,-y_0,-z_0)$.

It remains to discuss the others $6$ possible solutions:

$(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=(1,0,0)$:

$$\begin{pmatrix} x_0' \\ y_0' \\ z_0'\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}(-1)^\alpha+(-1)^\gamma & (-1)^\alpha+(-1)^{\gamma+1}& (-1)^\alpha+(-1)^{\gamma+1}\\ (-1)^\beta+(-1)^{\gamma+1} &(-1)^\beta+(-1)^\gamma& (-1)^{\beta+1}+(-1)^\gamma\\ (-1)^\alpha+(-1)^{\beta+1} &(-1)^\alpha+(-1)^{\beta+1}&(-1)^\alpha+(-1)^{\beta}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_0 \\ y_0 \\ z_0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1& -1\\ 0&1& 0\\ -1 &-1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_0 \\ y_0 \\ z_0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-y_0-z_0 \\ y_0 \\ -x_0-y_0\end{pmatrix}$$

Now we have impose that this solution belongs to $S^2$:

$$(-y_0-z_0)^2+y_0^2+(-x_0-y_0)^2=1+2y_0^2+2y_0z_0+2x_0y_0=1 \implies y_0(y_0+z_0+x_0)=0 \implies y_0=0 \quad \text{or} \quad  z_0=-x_0-y_0$$

If $z_0=-x_0-y_0$, then we would have $\begin{pmatrix} x_0' \\ y_0' \\ z_0'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-y_0-z_0 \\ y_0 \\ -x_0-y_0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x_0\\ y_0 \\ z_0\end{pmatrix}$, and we are done.

Instead, if $y_0=0$, then we would have $\begin{pmatrix} x_0' \\ y_0' \\ z_0'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-y_0-z_0 \\ y_0 \\ -x_0-y_0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -z_0\\0 \\ -x_0\end{pmatrix}$. However, we observe that we never used until now our coefficients $a,b,c$. We remember that we have also the relation

$$a(x_0')^2+b(y_0')^2+c(z_0')^2=ax_0^2+by_0^2+cz_0^2 \implies az_0^2+cx_0^2=ax_0^2+cz_0^2 \implies (a-c)(z_0^2-x_0^2)=0 \implies z_0=\pm x_0$$

because $a\neq c$, by assumption. If $z_0=x_0$,then we have obtained that $\begin{pmatrix} x_0' \\ y_0' \\ z_0'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -x_0\\0 \\ -x_0\end{pmatrix}$, so it is the opposite point of $\begin{pmatrix} x_0 \\ y_0 \\ z_0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x_0\\0 \\ x_0\end{pmatrix}$; instead if $z_0=-x_0$, then they are the same point $\begin{pmatrix} x_0' \\ y_0' \\ z_0'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x_0\\0 \\ -x_0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x_0 \\ y_0 \\ z_0\end{pmatrix}$.

We have concluded this case. You can do the same for the remain $5$ systems. Clearly, you will use there that $a\neq b$,$a \neq c$ and $b\neq c$.

Thus, we can conclude that $S^2/\mathbb Z_2\to \mathbb R^4$ is injective.

Now let us try to get the image of this interesting map:

Let us call by $X,Y,Z, W$ the variables of $\mathbb R^4$. We observe that

$$\begin{cases}
aYZ=X(ax^2) \\
bXZ=Y(by^2) \\
cXY=Z(cz^2)
\end{cases}\implies \begin{cases}
aY^2Z^2=XYZ(ax^2) \\
bX^2Z^2=XYZ(by^2) \\
cX^2Y^2=XYZ(cz^2)
\end{cases} \implies aY^2Z^2+ bX^2Z^2+cX^2Y^2=XYZ(ax^2+by^2+cz^2)=XYZW$$

Therefore one of the equations is

$$aY^2Z^2+bX^2Z^2+cX^2Y^2=XYZW.$$

We can use the same approach to deduce the remain equations:

$$Y^2Z^2+X^2Z^2+X^2Y^2=XYZ,$$

$$(W-a)(W-b)(W-c)+(c-b)^2X^2(W-a)+(c-a)^2Y^2(W-b)+(a-b)^2Z^2(W-c)=0$$

$$X[(b-c)^2X^2+(W-b)(W-c)]+[(c-a)^2Y^2X-(c-a)(b-a)YZ+(b-a)^2Z^2X]=0$$
$$Y[(a-c)^2Y^2+(W-a)(W-c)]+[(c-b)^2X^2Y-(a-b)(c-b)XZ+(a-b)^2Z^2Y]=0$$
$$Z[(a-b)^2Z^2+(W-a)(W-b)]+[(b-c)^2X^2Z-(a-c)(b-c)XY+(a-c)^2Y^2Z]=0$$

Are they enough? Let us take a point $(X, Y, Z, W)$ satisfying these equations and prove that it belongs to the image of our map:

First suppose that $XYZ\neq 0$. Since

$XYZ=Y^2Z^2+X^2Z^2+X^2Y^2>0$, then $\frac{YZ}{X}, \frac{XZ}{Y}, \frac{XY}{Z}>0$.

Observe that if $X>0$,  then only two options can occur, i.e. $Y>0$ and $Z>0$, or $Y<0$ and $Z<0$. Instead if $X<0$, then the others two options are $Y>0$, $Z<0$, or $Y<0$ and $Z>0$. This suggests to define

$x:=\sqrt{\frac{YZ}{X}}, y:=sign(XY)\sqrt{\frac{XZ}{Y}}$, and $z:=sign(XZ)\sqrt{\frac{XY}{Z}}$. By construction, we have  $(x,y,z)\in S^2$.

Then

$$\begin{cases}
 y\cdot z=sign(XY) \cdot sign(XZ)\cdot \vert X\vert=X; \\
 x \cdot z=sign(XZ)\cdot \vert Y\vert=Y;\\
 x\cdot y=sign(XY)\cdot \vert Z\vert=Z;\\
 ax^2+by^2+cz^2=W
\end{cases}.$$

Thus our point $(X,Y,Z,W)$ belongs to our image.

Now let us suppose that $XYZ=0$. By symmetry of the problem, let us study what happens just when $Z=0$. In this case we would have

$$ 0=XYZ=Y^2Z^2+X^2Z^2+X^2Y^2=X^2Y^2.$$

Therefore $X=0$, or $Y=0$. Suppose $Y=0$, then the third equation tells us

$$(W-a)(W-b)(W-c)=-(c-b)^2X^2(W-a)$$.

If $W\neq a$, then we have $X^2=-\frac{(W-b)(W-c)}{(c-b)^2}$. In particular, $W-b$ and $W-c$ have to be opposite sign. Let us define

$$x:=0, \quad y:=sign(X)\sqrt{\vert \frac{W-c}{b-c}\vert }, \quad z:=\sqrt{\vert -\frac{W-b}{b-c}\vert }.$$

Then

$$\begin{cases}
 y\cdot z=sign(X)\sqrt{\vert \frac{W-c}{b-c}\vert \cdot \vert -\frac{W-b}{b-c}\vert}=X; \\
 x \cdot z=0=Y;\\
 x\cdot y=0=Z;\\
 ax^2+by^2+cz^2=b\vert \frac{W-c}{b-c}\vert+c\vert -\frac{W-b}{b-c}\vert=W
\end{cases}.$$

Therefore, it remains only to study the points of the form $(X, 0,0, a)$, $(0,Y,0,b)$, and $(0,0,Z,c)$.

Here we have to use one of our remain three equations, depending by which points are we considering. For instance, let us consider the point $(X, 0,0, a)$. Then the fourth equation tells us

$$X[(b-c)^2X^2+(a-b)(a-c)]=0$$

If $X\neq 0$, then we would have $X^2=-\frac{(a-b)(a-c)}{(b-c)^2}$. In this case our point belongs to the image, since the point of coordinates

$$x:=0, \quad y:=sign(X)\sqrt{\vert \frac{a-c}{b-c}\vert }, \quad z:=\sqrt{\vert -\frac{a-b}{b-c}\vert }$$

maps to $(X, 0,0, a)$.

It remain to study the point $(0,0,0,a)$. Here it is simply: it belongs to our image since $(x,y,z)=(1,0,0)$ maps exactly to $(0,0,0,a)$.

We have proved that the image of our map is an algebraic surface given by the six equations

$$p_1(X,Y,Z,W):=aY^2Z^2+bX^2Z^2+cX^2Y^2-XYZW=0,$$
$$p_2(X,Y,Z,W):=Y^2Z^2+X^2Z^2+X^2Y^2-XYZ=0,$$
$$p_3(X,Y,Z,W):=(W-a)(W-b)(W-c)+(c-b)^2X^2(W-a)+(c-a)^2Y^2(W-b)+(a-b)^2Z^2(W-c)=0,$$
$$p_4(X,Y,Z,W):=X[(b-c)^2X^2+(W-b)(W-c)]+[(c-a)^2Y^2X-(c-a)(b-a)YZ+(b-a)^2Z^2X]=0,$$
$$p_5(X,Y,Z,W):=Y[(a-c)^2Y^2+(W-a)(W-c)]+[(c-b)^2X^2Y-(a-b)(c-b)XZ+(a-b)^2Z^2Y]=0,$$
$$p_6(X,Y,Z,W):=Z[(a-b)^2Z^2+(W-a)(W-b)]+[(b-c)^2X^2Z-(a-c)(b-c)XY+(a-c)^2Y^2Z]=0.$$

As every algebraic varieties on the field of real numbers, our surface is described as the zero locus of just a single equation, the sum of the squares of our $6$ polynomial:

$$\mathbb P^2(\mathbb R)\cong Z(p_1^2+\dots +p_6^2)\subseteq \mathbb R^4.$$

$\bf{Question \ 2:}$

I am sorry, I don't understand exactly what you want. What I can say is that if you consider the projection of you map to the first three coordinates, so basically if you consider the map sending $(x,y,x)\to (y\cdot z, x\cdot z, x\cdot y)\in \mathbb R^3$, then your map is an isomorphism only for $xyz\neq 0$ (I suggest you to follow my proof above of the injectivity of the map and see where are the obstructions, that should be when $x$ or $y$ or $z$ are equal to zero)

So, outside $xyz=0$, our map in $\mathbb R^3$ is an isomorphism to the image $XYZ\neq 0$, and it is defined by the equation

$$ Y^2Z^2+X^2Z^2+X^2Y^2-XYZ=0.$$

This surface is the so-called $\textbf{Roman Surface}$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_surface

Comment: True, my formulation is inexact (but still understandable). I think it is better to say that $f()$ is a smooth covering map from $S^2$ to a surface in $\mathbb{R}^4$, do you agree? On the other side, there is no result in your tentative answer which is not already mentioned in the description of the problem. You did not address the questions at all.

Comment: Uh, damn, I didn't see that you wrote the same equation haha. However, yes, I am agree with you. I will think more about the  answer.

Comment: I have tried to going on. I think it remains just the problem $XYZ=0$, although I guess our equations are not enough. It should there exists another one, that is a combination of our $2$ equations only when $XYZ\neq 0$. This equation should give more information about $W$, so I expect that is of the form $W^k=..$.  Maybe we could try together to get a solution.

Comment: The equations $Y^2Z^2 + X^2Z^2 + X^2Y^2 = XYZ$ and $aY^2Z^2 + bX^2Z^2 + cX^2Y^2 = XYZW$ are redundant, that is, implied by the four equations given afterwards. The details are in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Response to question 1**

This is a complement to the excellent answer of Federico Fallucca.

The ideal characterizing the image of $f()$ is already generated by
the following four polynomials:
$$
\begin{align}
  & (b - c)^2X^3 + (c - a)^2XY^2 + (a - b)^2XZ^2 + (W - b)(W - c)X - (a - b)(a - c)YZ       & (C_0) \\
  & (c - a)^2Y^3 + (a - b)^2YZ^2 + (b - c)^2YX^2 + (W - c)(W - a)Y - (b - c)(b - a)ZX       & (C_1) \\
  & (a - b)^2Z^3 + (b - c)^2ZX^2 + (c - a)^2ZY^2 + (W - a)(W - b)Z - (c - a)(c - b)XY       & (C_2) \\
  & (b - c)^2(W - a)X^2 + (c - a)^2(W - b)Y^2 + (a - b)^2(W - c)Z^2 + (W - a)(W - b)(W - c) & (C_3)
\end{align}
$$
In particular, this ideal contains the following two polynomials
(naturally derived from the constraints $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and
$ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 = W$, but superseded by the generators
above):
$$
\begin{align}
  & Y^2Z^2 + Z^2X^2 + X^2Y^2 - XYZ     & (D_0) \\
  & aY^2Z^2 + cX^2Y^2 + bZ^2X^2 - XYZW & (D_1)
\end{align}
$$
Indeed:
$$
\begin{align}
    D_0 &= \frac{(b - c)YZC_0 + (c - a)ZXC_1 + (a - b)XYC_2}{(a - b)(b - c)(c - a)} \\
    D_1 &= \frac{a(b - c)YZC_0 + b(c - a)ZXC_1 + c(a - b)XYC_2}{(a - b)(b - c)(c - a)}
\end{align}
$$

**Response to question 2**

The real projective hemisphere $S$ (that is, the real unit sphere with
opposite points identified) can be identified with the real projective
plane $P$ by the following map:
$$
\begin{align}
    P & \longrightarrow S \\
    [\bar{x} : \bar{y} : \bar{z}] & \longrightarrow (x, y, z)
  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\bar{x}^2 + \bar{y}^2 + \bar{z}^2}} \cdot (\bar{x}, \bar{y}, \bar{z})
\end{align}
$$
Thus, for inversing $f()$, it is enough to determine $(x, y, z)$ up to
a non-zero constant scaling factor, that is, to determine
$[x : y : z]$.

Assume $(X, Y, Z, W) = f(x, y, z)$ from now on; in particular:
$$
\begin{align}
  & x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \\
  & X = y \cdot z \\
  & Y = z \cdot x \\
  & Z = x \cdot y \\
  & W = a \cdot x^2 + b \cdot y^2 + c \cdot z^2
\end{align}
$$

Our goal is to express $[x : y : z]$ as polynomial functions
$g_i(X, Y, Z, W)$, using the constraints above. For any polynomial
$t_i(x, y, z)$, we have:
$$
    [t_i(x, y, z) \cdot x : t_i(x, y, z) \cdot y : t_i(x, y, z) \cdot z]
  = [x : y : z]
$$
unless $t_i(x, y, z) = 0$. The left-hand side is said to be determinate
at $(x, y, z)$ if $t_i(x, y, z)$ does not vanish, and indeterminate
otherwise. We have thus to find polynomials $t_i()$ such that the
left-hand side can be expressed in the $(X, Y, Z, W)$ coordinates,
that is:
$$
    g_i(X, Y, Z, W) = [x : y : z]
$$
Furthermore, we have to find enough of such polynomials $t_i()$ resp.
$g_i()$ such that, for each $(X, Y, Z, W)$ in the image of $f()$, some of
these polynomials is determinate at $(X, Y, Z, W)$, that is,
$g_i(X, Y, Z, W) \neq [0 : 0 : 0]$.

A possibility would be to choose $t_0(x, y, z) = x \cdot y \cdot z$, which
yields:
$$
\begin{align}
    [x : y : z]
 &= [t_0(x, y, z) \cdot x : t_0(x, y, z) \cdot y : t_0(x, y, z) \cdot z] \\
 &= [x \cdot y \cdot z \cdot x : x \cdot y \cdot z \cdot y : x \cdot y \cdot z \cdot z ] \\
 &= [Y \cdot Z : Z \cdot X : X \cdot Y]
\end{align}
$$
and thus:
$$
    g_0(X, Y, Z, W) \overset{\underset{\mathrm{def}}{}}{=}
    [Y \cdot Z : Z \cdot X : X \cdot Y]
$$
which is indeterminate at $(X, Y, Z, W)$ exactly if
$X \cdot Y \cdot Z = 0$, or, equivalently, $x \cdot y \cdot z = 0$.

But more comprehensive polynomials $t_i()$ can be derived using the
following equality:
$$
\begin{align}
    (W - a)
 &= a \cdot x^2 + b \cdot y^2 + c \cdot z^2 - a \\
 &= a \cdot x^2 + b \cdot y^2 + c \cdot z^2 - a \cdot (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \\
 &= (b - a) \cdot y^2 + (c - a) \cdot z^2
\end{align}
$$

Analogously:
$$
    (W - b) = (c - b) \cdot z^2 + (a - b) \cdot x^2 \\
    (W - c) = (a - c) \cdot x^2 + (b - c) \cdot y^2
$$
from which follows:
$$
\begin{align}
    (W - a) \cdot x^2
 &= (b - a) \cdot x^2 \cdot y^2 + (c - a) \cdot z^2 \cdot x^2 \\
 &= (b - a) \cdot Z^2 + (c - a) \cdot Y^2
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
    (c - b) \cdot (W - a) \cdot z^2
 &= (W - a) \cdot ((W - b) + (b - a) \cdot x^2) \\
 &= (W - a) \cdot (W - b) + (b - a)^2 \cdot Z^2 + (b - a) \cdot (c - a) \cdot Y^2
\end{align}
$$

Analogously:
$$
\begin{align}
    (W - b) \cdot y^2 &= (c - b) \cdot X^2 + (a - b) \cdot Z^2 \\
    (a - c) \cdot (W - b) \cdot x^2 &= (W - b) \cdot (W - c) + (c - b)^2 \cdot X^2 + (c - b) \cdot (a - b) \cdot Z^2 \\
    (W - c) \cdot z^2 &= (a - c) \cdot Y^2 + (b - c) \cdot X^2 \\
    (b - a) \cdot (W - c) \cdot y^2 &= (W - c) \cdot (W - a) + (a - c)^2 \cdot Y^2 + (a - c) \cdot (b - c) \cdot X^2
\end{align}
$$

Choosing $t_1(x, y, z) = (a - c) \cdot (W - b) \cdot x$ yields:
$$
\begin{align}
    [x : y : z]
 &= [t_1(x, y, z) \cdot x : t_1(x, y, z) \cdot y : t_1(x, y, z) \cdot z] \\
 &= [(a - c) \cdot (W - b) \cdot x^2 : (a - c) \cdot (W - b) \cdot x \cdot y : (a - c) \cdot (W - b) \cdot z \cdot x] \\
 &= [(W - b) \cdot (W - c) + (c - b)^2 \cdot X^2 + (c - b) \cdot (a - b) \cdot Z^2 : (a - c) \cdot (W - b) \cdot Z : (a - c) \cdot (W - b) \cdot Y]
\end{align}
$$
And thus:
$$
    g_1(X, Y, Z, W) \overset{\underset{\mathrm{def}}{}}{=}
    [(W - b) \cdot (W - c) + (c - b)^2 \cdot X^2 + (c - b) \cdot (a - b) \cdot Z^2 : (a - c) \cdot (W - b) \cdot Z : (a - c) \cdot (W - b) \cdot Y]
$$

Choosing $t_2(x, y, z) = (b - a) \cdot (W - c) \cdot y$ resp.
$t_3(x, y, z) = (c - b) \cdot (W - a) \cdot z$ yields, analogously:
$$
    g_2(X, Y, Z, W) \overset{\underset{\mathrm{def}}{}}{=}
    [(b - a) \cdot (W - c) \cdot Z : (W - c) \cdot (W - a) + (a - c)^2 \cdot Y^2 + (a - c) \cdot (b - c) \cdot X^2 : (b - a) \cdot (W - c) \cdot X]
    \\
    g_3(X, Y, Z, W) \overset{\underset{\mathrm{def}}{}}{=}
    [(c - b) \cdot (W - a) \cdot Y : (c - b) \cdot (W - a) \cdot X : (W - a) \cdot (W - b) + (b - a)^2 \cdot Z^2 + (b - a) \cdot (c - a) \cdot Y^2]
$$

The constraints for these last three maps $g_1()$, $g_2()$ and $g_3()$
to all be indeterminate at $f(x, y, z)$ for some $(x, y, z)$ on the
real projective hemisphere are
$t_1(x, y, z) = t_2(x, y, z) = t_3(x, y, z) = 0$, that is,
$
    (a - c) \cdot (W - b) \cdot x
  = (b - a) \cdot (W - c) \cdot y
  = (c - b) \cdot (W - a) \cdot z = 0
$,
that is, by the equalities established above:
$$
    (W - b) \cdot (W - c) + (c - b)^2 \cdot X^2 + (c - b) \cdot (a - b) \cdot Z^2 = 0 \\
    (W - c) \cdot (W - a) + (a - c)^2 \cdot Y^2 + (a - c) \cdot (b - c) \cdot X^2 = 0 \\
    (W - a) \cdot (W - b) + (b - a)^2 \cdot Z^2 + (b - a) \cdot (c - a) \cdot Y^2 = 0
$$
that is, by expressing (X, Y, Z, W) in terms of (x, y, z) and simplifying:
$$
    x \cdot ((c - b) \cdot z^2 + (a - b) \cdot x^2) = 0 \\
    y \cdot ((a - c) \cdot x^2 + (b - c) \cdot y^2) = 0 \\
    z \cdot ((b - a) \cdot y^2 + (c - a) \cdot z^2) = 0
$$
which have no solution on the real projective hemisphere, such that no
point of the hemisphere has an image $f(x, y, z)$ at which all three
maps $g_1()$, $g_2()$ and $g_3()$ are indeterminate.

In other words, the inverse of $f()$ is at least one of the polynomials
$g_1()$, $g_2()$ and $g_3()$, whichever is determinate, depending their
argument (a point $(X, Y, Z, W)$ in the image of $f()$), and there is no
argument at which all three are indeterminate.

Finally, the function $f()$ can be equivalently defined on the real
projective plane:
$$
\begin{align}
    f([x : y : z])
 &= f\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}, \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}\right) \\
 &= \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \cdot (y \cdot z, z \cdot x, x \cdot y, a \cdot x^2 + b \cdot y^2 + c \cdot z^2)
\end{align}
$$
and thus the real projective plane and the image of $f()$ are
birationally equivalent.

Comment: I don't understand your notation. Our map $f$ is from $S^2$ to $\mathbb C^4$. Please call the candidate inverse with $g\colon \mathbb C^4\to S^2/Z_2$ and show why do you think that $f \circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are the identity map

Comment: @FedericoFallucca Notice that I consider the base field to be $\mathbb{R}$, otherwise, the identification of the projective plan with the sphere with opposite points identified fails. The point of considering projective coordinates $[x : y : z]$ is: No square root is needed (no division by $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$); indeed, $f()$ can be adapted: $f(x, y, z) = \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \cdot (y \cdot z, z \cdot x, x \cdot y, a \cdot x^2 + b \cdot y^2 + c \cdot z^2)$. Question 2 means thus: Are the real projective plane and the image of $f()$ birationally equivalent ?

Comment: @FedericoFallucca I finally found and posted a solution: The real projective plane and the algebraic 4-dimensional variety in question are thus birationally equivalent.

Comment: Very interesting, I will answer you in the next days okay? I need time to read it and I am too busy right now :)